# Reduce output to desired file based on Key/value pair (HADOOP)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, key-value, reduce

is it possible to send reducer output to more than one file based on the key ? like,

```
if(key1)
 {
        //output to file1 using context.write() or otherwise
  }
 else
 {
        //output to file2 using context.write() or otherwise
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use conditional logic in your reducer together with the [`MultipleOutputs`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.3-alpha/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputs.html) class to achieve what you are looking to do. They have an example of how to do this in the javadoc linked.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach would be implementing a custom [Partitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.3-alpha/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Partitioner.html). This way one could just run two (multiple) reducers and partition accordingly based on the key's value.